# Crear una expresión regular para validar html de freemaker

Tags: java, regex

mi consulta el la siguiente, hoy en día estoy validando el código html con jsoup para limpiar javascript por ataques XSS, por ejemplo yo tengo la siguiente sintaxis dentro de mi archivo html:

```
<div class="row">
<#list things as thing> 
</#list>
</div>
```

y después de realizar un parse con jsoup sale asi:

```
<div class="row">
&lt;#list things as thing&gt;
&lt;/#list&gt;
</div>
```

encontré este post que lo tome como ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671149/jsoup-parse-trashing-freemarker-tags

pero me pregunto si se puede realizar el cambio de <# "lo que este adentro"> por [# "lo que este adentro"], sumando la etiqueta de cierre con expresiones regulares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya pude resolver mi problema, lo que quería hacer es mantener el formato de mi documento html freemarker y para esto reemplace a través de una expresión regular antes de realizar el parse y lo que realice fue lo siguiente:

```
  Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("</#(.+)>");
  Matcher m = patt.matcher(htmlString);
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(htmlString.length());
  while (m.find()) {
    String markCloseFreemarker = m.group();
    markCloseFreemarker = markCloseFreemarker.replaceAll("<", "[").replaceAll(">","]");
    m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(markCloseFreemarker));
  }
  m.appendTail(sb);

  patt= Pattern.compile("<#(.+)>");
  m = patt.matcher(sb.toString());
  sb = new StringBuffer(sb.toString().length());
  while (m.find()) {
        String markCloseFreemarker = m.group();
        markCloseFreemarker = markCloseFreemarker.replaceAll("<", "[").replaceAll(">","]");
        m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(markCloseFreemarker));
    }
  m.appendTail(sb);

  return sb.toString();
```

y una vez que haya procesado y quiera recuperarlo en formato string devuelta el html, hago lo siguiente:

```
  Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\[/#(.+)\\]");
  Matcher m = patt.matcher(htmlString);
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(htmlString.length());
  while (m.find()) {
    String markFreemarker = m.group();
    markFreemarker = markFreemarker.replaceAll("\\[", "<").replaceAll("\\]",">");
    m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(markFreemarker));
  }
  m.appendTail(sb);

  patt= Pattern.compile("\\[#(.+)\\]");
  m = patt.matcher(sb.toString());
  sb = new StringBuffer(sb.toString().length());
  while (m.find()) {
        String markFreemarker = m.group();
        markFreemarker = markFreemarker.replaceAll("\\[", "<").replaceAll("\\]",">");
        m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(markFreemarker));
    }
  m.appendTail(sb);

  return sb.toString();
```

espero que alguien le sirva, saludos.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes aceptar tu respuesta :)

Comment: Gracias Julio :)